How can i pass build model in deepface library?
I am using face recognition library deepface,and using find method for identify images i need to pass prebuild model to that method but it is not working can any one explain how can i do that?
output2 = DeepFace.find(img2,img1_path,model_name=model_name)



can you please add error details?

Built models were passed in the previous versions of deepface. Now, if you build a model once, it is being stored as singletonish. In other words, it will not be build again. For instance, if you build Facenet model with build_model function, then find function will use the pretrained model and you do not have to do anything more.
from deepface import DeepFace

# build model once
model = DeepFace.build_model("Facenet")

dfs = DeepFace.find(img1_path, img2_path, model_name = "Facenet")

